# Redirect to an instance of Twisted web server

Tags: python, windows, twisted, twisted.web

We have a Twisted application running as a Windows Service, serving the web application on a given port, e.g. https://localhost:8880/portal, etc. Each Windows Service is configured to serve on a particular port.

We would like to be able to redirect the request based to the right port, based on the host specified, e.g. https://bob.com/portal -> https://localhost:8880/portal.

Is this possible with tools and features available in Windows, or even with 3rd party?

Comment: This question is not entirely clear.

Comment: I believe you're trying to make a proxy server. There are tons of examples on the web on how to do this using Twisted. Try one of them and come back here if you run into trouble. Truth be told, if you can, use Nginx, Apache or any other dedicated web server, it's less to worry about.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone how can I better clarify the question?

Comment: @notorious.no the Twisted application is out of my control for this purpose. They were built to run as Windows Services and cannot be run in a web server, such as IIS, Apache, etc. I am currently trying IIS' Application Request Routing but not having much success at the moment.